# How do I remove myself as content creator of an unpublished Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I was added as content creator for a Facebook Page that started posting severely abusive and explicit content of late, and as a result, got unpublished for violations of policy. I want to disassociate myself with this controversial page as I am severely offended by the content that is being posted by other admins, and I had no idea about the true intentions of this page when they added me as content creator.

However, when I try to remove myself from *Edit* > *Manage Admin Roles*, I get an error saying, *You have been temporarily blocked from performing this action*. I keep getting logged out of Facebook every time an abusive post is removed, and that is getting rather annoying. How do I remove myself as content creator from an unpublished/banned Facebook page?